# passing variable to different classed in java

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

i'm doing my java assignment, i got a GUI class that handle all the graphical user interface components such as button, i defined all the button in GUI file and i want to add action Listener to the button but i want the action Listener action to be inside add Button Action Listener class, which means when i clicked the button it will call the action listener's action in add Button Action Listener class, below is the code

```
public static void mainLayout(){
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();

    buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar("Applications");

    JButton addplayer = new JButton ("AddPlayer");
    JButton placebet = new JButton("Place Bet");

    buttonPane.add(addplayer);
    buttonPane.add(placebet);

    frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.setSize(500,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);  
}
```

and for Action Listener class

```
public class addButtonActionListener {

    public static void addPlayer() {
        addplayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Add Success!!");
       }
    });

    placebet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Place Bet Success!!");
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Edmond Lee, what is your question?

Comment: hi DerMike, my problem is i want to call the Action Listener in the addButtonActionListener class which is the second bunch of code when i clicked the JButton on GUI class is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Follow naming conventions, your code 'll be a lot easier to read.
secondly: your trial to create an actionlistener is wrong. that class needs to implement actionlistener, and have the business logic within the actionPerformed method you supply.

that you can add to the button.